# In Dojo how can we set a selected dropdown option?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

i am using dropdown widget in dojo (dijit), i want to set the selected option the top menu

i tried this code:

```
dijit.byId('projectId').addOption({ label: item.projname , value: item.projid, selected:true  });
```

here the selected: true

is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asker's code is not correct as the `selected` property applies for the construction of the object. As PaulR suggested, the asker should use `dijit.byId('projectId').set("value",item.projid);` when the select widget has already been created.

Aside: I would suggest using the AMD module `"dijit/registry"` rather than the root `dijit` object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, "selected: true" is the correct way to specify the selected item. See https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Select.html.

I noticed the same issue in the past, and noticed that this only works correctly when an option has a value. So, can you check if "item.projid" contains a value?

Comment: "item.projid" has values: check this   [{"postedprojnum":"1","projname":"dashboard","projid":1},{"postedprojnum":"1","projname":"cisco","projid":3},{"postedprojnum":"1","projname":"hcl","projid":4},{"postedprojnum":"1","projname":"addnew","projid":5}]

Comment: That's indeed strange. Can you try to set the value of the dropdown widget explicitly?

dijit.byId('projectId').set("value","1");